# Does it follow that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ is a finite measure, $f_n \to f$ almost everywhere, each $f_n$ is integrable, $f$ is integrable, and $\int |f_n - f| \to 0$. Does it follow that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, without assuming $f_n\to  f$ almost everywhere.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N$ so $\int|f_n-f|<\epsilon/2$ for $n>N$. A finite family of integrable functions is uniformly integrable, so there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(A)<\delta$ implies $\int_A|g|<\epsilon/2$ for $g=f$ and also for $g=f_1,\dots,f_N$. If $\mu(A)<\delta$ and $n>N$ then $\int_A|f_n|\le\int_A|f_n-f|+\int_A|f|<\epsilon$.